# HTML tables must not be deleted in WYSIWYG editor

Tags: html, moodle, wysiwyg, lms

Hi i would like to know how can i have tables that i add into a wysiwyg editor that cannot be removed or deleted, but filled in.

Scenario, im using a LMS called Moodle and adding in tables to a question but the students tend to keep deleting the tables in the wysiwyg editor were they should provide the answer.

i tried and found nothing close to this to be honest.

Comment: It won't be possible since all WYSIWYG editors are based on the contenteditable elements of HTML, and there is no way to prevent a child element from getting removed under such settings.

Comment: You should reach out to moodle's support. Or tell your students to not delete the tables.

Comment: Use another tool where the students can only input their answers. Chose the right tool for the job :)

Comment: create an activity plugin or an editor plugin (call it maybe table_activity_editor) and then in Javascript you would have to create your own editor to handle all the editing.  If you treat each table cell as a separate entity and stick to plain text (no pictures, formatting etc) then it would be possible if not trivial.